Is $\sqrt{x+C}$ equal to $\sqrt{x} + C$ if C is the constant of integration?
I know it breaks a law of mathematics but can I not say it holds true for this example? In both expressions C can increase or decrease everything and be replaced with a numerical constant and isn't that the only point of it? I ask because I see it written like this in my textbook as the final simplified answer.

more context can help

Please make the body of your MSE posts self-contained: don't rely on the title to provide important information. Also, to answer this question, we need some more context. Where does the problem come from and what have you tried?

No. $\sqrt{x+C}$ can be viewed as a horizontal translation of the graph $\sqrt{x}$, whereas $\sqrt{x} + C$ can be viewed as a vertical translation of the graph $\sqrt{x}$.

See my response to the answer of Dan.

If you're trying to ascertain whether two expressions are equivalent answers to an indefinite integral (i.e., up to an integration constant), take the derivative of both and compare. In this case, you certainly don't end up with the same thing (one expression depends on $C$ and the other doesn't).

The derivative of $\sqrt x+C$ is $1/(2\sqrt x)$, no matter what $C$ is, so $\int{1\over2\sqrt x}=\sqrt x+C$.
The derivative of $\sqrt{x+C}$ is $1/(2\sqrt{x+C})$, which is not $1/(2\sqrt x)$ (unless $C=0$, which defeats the whole purpose of the arbitrary constant), and that's why, in the context of integration, $\sqrt{x+C}$ is wrong.

No (unless $C = 0$, of course).  Even if you intend different constants in the two expressions (Does $\sqrt{x + C} = \sqrt{x} + D$), the expressions aren't equivalent.  For one thing, the domains are different:

$\sqrt{x + C}$ is real if $x \ge -C$.
$\sqrt{x} + D$ is real if $x \ge 0$.


Tricky response.  I feel that it is important to stretch the original poster's intuition.  In fact, if you overlook the difference in domain's, and you construe the original poster's assertion to be that for any fixed constants $~C,x~$ there exists constants $~D,E~$ such that $$~\sqrt{x + D} = \sqrt{x} + C, ~~~\text{and} ~~~\sqrt{x + C} = \sqrt{x} + E,$$ then the assertion is true.

Consider $\sqrt{x + 9} = \sqrt{x} + C$. At $x = 0$, $\sqrt{0 + 9} = \sqrt{9} = 3 = \sqrt{0} + 3$, which implies that $C = 3$. But then at $x = 16$, we have $\sqrt{16 + 9} = \sqrt{25} = 5$, but $\sqrt{16} + 3 = 4 + 3 = 7$.

I think it's important to remember why antiderivatives have a constant of integration, and to understand the implications of such a term.
For an integrable function $f(x)$, we call $F(x)$ an antiderivative of $f$ if $F'(x) = f(x)$; that is to say, the derivative of $F$ equals $f$.  For this reason, the antiderivative is not unique, since the derivative of a constant is zero.  Thus there is in general an infinite class of antiderivatives for a given integrable function $f$.
When $f$ is continuous, then the family of such antiderivatives may be parametrized by a single constant of integration, which is often denoted $C$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[F(x) + C] = F'(x) = f,$$
for any constant $C$ with respect to $x$.  This is why the function $\sqrt{x+C}$ does not work:  its derivative with respect to $x$ remains a function of $C$; as such, it violates the property that the derivative does not depend on $C$, which was imposed as a result of the condition that all antiderivatives of $f$ must have the same derivative.  The discussion about $C = 0$ is irrelevant, because the family of antiderivatives is parametrized by $C$; allowing it to take on specific values negates the purpose of the parametrization in the first place.
